# Getting confused in @output decorator behaviour

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I am going through input output decorator and tried to implement in below example for demo purpose, to understand the importance of these decorators:

**home.component.html**

```
<app-login>
  <app-checkbox (checkBoxValue)="checkBoxValueChanged($event)"></app-checkbox>
</app-login>
```

**login.comp.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent{
  public checkBoxValueChanged(event){
    alert("called from here "+event)
  }
}
```

**login.comp.html**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="email"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <input type="button" value="login"/>
</form>
```

**checkbox.comp.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkbox',
  templateUrl: './checkbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkbox.component.css']
})
export class CheckboxComponent{
  @Output() checkBoxValue : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  valueChanged(value){
    this.checkBoxValue.emit(value)
  }
}
```

**checkbox.comp.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Y" (change)="valueChanged($event.target.value)"/> Remember Me
```

As per my understanding checkBoxValueChanged should be in login component as checkbox component is called inside login component but this is not working. I am getting error of `ERROR TypeError: _co.checkBoxValueChanged is not a function` if i write checkBoxValueChanged  inside login component. But when i write this function inside home component everything works fine but i am confused why its not working when it is in login component.

Comment: Because checkBoxValueChanged is called inside of HomeComponent template. If you don't have such method in home.comp.ts, you get the error. What is that you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have `checkBoxValueChanged` function in `home.component.ts` component as you are using `app-checkbox` component in `home.component.ts`, simply move `checkBoxValueChanged` function to  `home.component.ts` from `login.comp.ts` and you will receive the emitted value, rest is perfect!!

or if you  want emitted value in `login.comp.ts`, don't follow above point rather move your `<app-checkbox (checkBoxValue)="checkBoxValueChanged($event)"></app-checkbox>` tag to `login.comp.html`...

Hope it helps you!! :)

Consider upvoting please if it helped!